# merge two javascript image to url

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I've been researching this for some time and I can't seem to find anything else that has this problem or anything similar. I am using javascript to create a quiz, and when the user gets the result of the quiz, they are generated with an image and their facebook profile image.

What I want to do, is when they get these images, they can then share the images, merged as one, on Facebook. Currently I have a running demo  [here](http://webwaygate.com/ian/quizFB/index.html) where you can see the results that I am talking about.

My code for the facebook image is:

```
function getPhoto()
{
  FB.api('/me/picture?type=normal', function(response) {
      console.log(response.data.url);
      var str="<br/><img class='fbImage' src='"+response.data.url+"'/>";
      document.getElementById("quizResultsCopy").innerHTML+=str;

});
```

and in a external javascript file, the result image is here:

```
 (plugin.method.inRange(0.0, 0.19, percent)) {
                level = 4;

                getPhoto();
                 div.innerHTML +=  'What can we say – green is definitely your colour. And kudos on scoring some of thebest real estate in the world! With cawfee in your blood and the smoky scent of hawt dawgs whipping around your (colossal) nose, you are the epitome of freedom and friendship. Your warm, welcoming personality can light up a room (or a harbour) and your social calendar is out of control; people literally line up for hours to see you. We suspect sitting down to a recording of Saturday Night Live or enjoying a boozy mimosa brunch are high on your travel bucket list. If not, you better update your list ;) <br> <br> <button id="shareonfacebook" onclick="shareonfb()" >ShareOnFaceBook</button> <br> <br> <img class="quizImage" src="resultimg.png" width="800"> ';

            }
```

I am not sure if I have supplied all the relevant code, If i haven't I can supply more.

Comment: you need to create the image via php, search for image merge with php on google, plenty of good results.

Comment: Yea, i was just wondering if it could be done with only javascript. I dont really want to use php. Its looking like I'll have to though